# How to store a word from file in a separate variable?

Tags: c, file

In this code, I want to select a word and save it in a separate variable. Same with all the words in a file. I have given the option (which I commented) to select any word from the file and when a user will select that word, it should be stored in a variable. How to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  FILE * fr = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  char string[100];

  if((fr = fopen("file.txt", "r")) == NULL){
    printf("Error! Opening file");
    exit(1);
  }
  while (fgets(string, 100, fr) != NULL){
    printf("%s", string);
    // printf("Write word to extract: ");
    // scanf("%s", ch);
    fclose(fr);
  }
```

Comment: Firstly, you should stop opening same file twice without closing. Secondly, you should stop closing the file in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the use of this as the user inputs the same word. But here you go.

Using `scanf()` for user input of word to look for.
Using `fgets()` to get row from file into string.
Using `strtok()` to step through string using the delimiters given in `#define DELIMITERS`.

The word scanned from the file is stored in `saved_word`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DELIMITERS " ,.-_!?"
#define STRING_LEN 100

int main(){
    FILE * fr = NULL;
    char string[STRING_LEN]; // Buffer for row in file
    char input[STRING_LEN]; // Buffer for input word
    char saved_word[STRING_LEN]; // To save the word in

    memset(string, 0, sizeof string);
    memset(input, 0, sizeof input);
    memset(saved_word, 0, sizeof saved_word);

    fr = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    if (fr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    char* word = NULL;

    /**
     * User input of word to look for within file
     */
    printf("string: %s\n", string);
    printf("Enter what word you want to find: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Start scanning file.\n");
    while (fgets(string, STRING_LEN-1, fr) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Scanned row.\n");

        /**
         * Use strtok() to scan through the row, stored in string
         * Manual says to only have string input parameter on first call
         */
        word = strtok(string, DELIMITERS);
        
        int diff;
        while (word != NULL)
        {
            diff = strcmp(input, word);
            if (diff == 0)
            {
                // Matching words! 
                printf("Found the word: %s\n", word);
                strcpy(saved_word, word);
            }
            word = strtok(NULL, DELIMITERS);
        }
        
    }

    fclose(fr);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you wrote

Maybe you can read a word from the user and "extract" it from the file, a search.

For an user to be able to select a word from the file such word must be read into a variable. And for the program to be able to compare the words in the file against a word in a variable you must read the words in the file to another variable.

In your code you are opening and closing the file multiple times. Check it out.